# Difference between ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges and fixture.detectChanges

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-changedetection

Let's say we have a component - `MyComponent` with `OnPush` change detection strategy which injects `ChangeDetectorRef`  in order to manually trigger `detectChanges()` (for example inside the subscriptions or somewhere else).

And we also have a test for this component. So when we get the instance of `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)` - we can also trigger `detectChanges()` to perform data binding in our tests.

My question is - what's the difference between these two methods in both cases? Can we get the same result if I trigger `component.changeDetecotrRef.detectChanges()` in the tests instead of triggering `fixture.detectChanges()`?

Answer (score 5):

They technically do the same thing, but `changeDetecotrRef.detectChanges()` is a piece of component functionality while `fixture.detectChanges()` is a shim for testing.

The difference is that `changeDetecotrRef.detectChanges()` triggers change detection in the compiled Angular app, while `fixture.detectChanges()` triggers change detection in the test environment. The former is designed to work with a fully compiled Angular app, while the latter works with a fixture designed to emulate a full Angular app.

The #1 rule of unit testing is to not change code to fit a test, so use `changeDetecotrRef.detectChanges()` in component code when you *need* change detection in order for the component to function, and use `fixture.detectChanges()` to shim a test when change detection is expected to happen (like simulating user input or, indeed, like calling `changeDetecotrRef.detectChanges()` in the component).